# Plotly update_menus hiding traces problem

Tags: plotly, visualization, plotly-python

Newbie in Plotly with Python and StackOverflow here. I have created a figure that includes a number of box plots, a scatter plot and a few more elements that can be relayed out.

My data have gaps that I want to optionally toggle on and off from appearing in the graph using a dropdown list (see Image 1).

[image: Image 1]

In one case, I can hide the gaps successfully but the scatter plot loses its X axis values and is graphed after the end of the labeled data (see Image 2). This is produced by this line of code: `dict(label="Exclude missing data", method="update", args=[{"x":df.Run[x_some],"visible": x_some}])`

[image: Image 2]

In the other case I can hide the gaps in the data, the scatter plot works but the labels of the X axis that were "hidden" move to the end of the graph (see Image 3). This is produced by this line of code: `dict(label="Exclude missing data", method="update", args=[{"visible": x_some}])`

[image: Image 3]

Are there any hints on what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Please find some sample code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio
import datetime as dt
import plotly.graph_objects as go

pio.renderers.default = 'browser'
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
fig = go.Figure()
N = 100
ydata = np.random.randint(600, 1200, size=(100, 5))
x = ["R"+str(i) for i in range(len(ydata))]
df = pd.DataFrame(ydata, columns=["M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5"])
df["X"] = x
gaps = np.r_[20:40, 60:70]
df.iloc[gaps, 0:5] = np.nan
df["Mean"] = df.iloc[:, 0:5].mean(axis=1).round(0)
cols = df.columns.str.contains("M")

# %% figure setup
layout = dict(
    height=700, width=1500,
    xaxis_title="Run",
    xaxis=dict(autorange=False, range=[0, N], type="category"),
    yaxis=dict(autorange=True),
    font=dict(family="Courier New, monospace", size=12, color="RebeccaPurple"),
    showlegend=False
)

fig.layout = layout

mean_line = go.Scatter(x=df.X, y=df.Mean, connectgaps=True, mode='lines+markers', name='Mean line', showlegend=False)

boxes = [go.Box(name=df.X[i], y=df.iloc[i, cols], boxpoints=False, boxmean=True, notched=True, showlegend=False) for i in range(N)]

fig.add_traces(boxes)

x_all = df.index == df.index
x_some = (df.Mean > 0).values

fig.add_trace(mean_line)

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[
    dict(type="dropdown", direction="down", buttons=list([
        dict(label="Include missing data", method="update", args=[{"visible": x_all}]),
        dict(label="Exclude missing data", method="update", args=[{"visible": x_some}])
    ]), pad={"l": 10, "t": 10}, showactive=True, x=0.23, xanchor="left", y=1.1, yanchor="top")])

z = fig.to_dict()
fig.show()
```

Comment: can you include the code you used to produce this figure as well as some sample data that we can use to reproduce the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Thank you for having a look at the post. I edited in some code as you suggested.

Comment: thanks! this will make it much easier for users here to help you debug. however, i've tried running your sample code but it seems to work as expected – do I need additional traces to reproduce the problematic behavior?

Comment: I have changed the code slightly to make more gaps to the data.
This link shows how it's plotting for me: [link](https://imgur.com/EJSExlw)
And this how it looks after triggering the action (notice the labels on the xaxis at the end of the graph): [link](https://imgur.com/rvJS1sC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is occurring is because you forgot to account for the last trace which is the scatter, and it still includes x-values that are `NaN`. (there are 100 box traces and 1 scatter trace, so `x_all` and `x_some` should actually have length 101 – in your original code, these two boolean arrays have length 100, but plotly assumes that you mean to show the last scatter trace)

To fix this, we can add another scatter trace with missing values dropped – we can make this not visible by default, and only show this scatter when you select the `"Exclude missing data"` from the dropdown.

Note: `x_all` and `x_some` will now have length 102. `x_all` should look like `[True,... True, True, False]` because we show the first 100 boxplots, and then show the first scatter without nulls dropped, but then don't show the second scatter which has nulls dropped. And `x_some` should look like `[True...False... False... True, False, True]` because some of the box plots traces that are empty won't be shown, and then we don't show the first scatter without nulls dropped, but show the second scatter which has nulls dropped.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio
import datetime as dt
import plotly.graph_objects as go

pio.renderers.default = 'browser'
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
fig = go.Figure()
N = 100
ydata = np.random.randint(600, 1200, size=(100, 5))
x = ["R"+str(i) for i in range(len(ydata))]
df = pd.DataFrame(ydata, columns=["M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5"])
df["X"] = x
gaps = np.r_[20:40, 60:70]
df.iloc[gaps, 0:5] = np.nan
df["Mean"] = df.iloc[:, 0:5].mean(axis=1).round(0)
cols = df.columns.str.contains("M")

# figure setup
layout = dict(
    height=700, width=1500,
    xaxis_title="Run",
    xaxis=dict(autorange=False, range=[0, N], type="category"),
    yaxis=dict(autorange=True),
    font=dict(family="Courier New, monospace", size=12, color="RebeccaPurple"),
    showlegend=False
)

fig.layout = layout

mean_line = go.Scatter(x=df.X, y=df.Mean, connectgaps=True, mode='lines+markers', name='Mean line', showlegend=False)

## create mean line with excluded values missing (not visible by default)
df_non_null = df.dropna()
mean_line_exclude_missing = go.Scatter(x=df_non_null.X, y=df_non_null.Mean, connectgaps=False, mode='lines+markers', name='Mean line', showlegend=False, visible=False)

boxes = [go.Box(name=df.X[i], y=df.iloc[i, cols], boxpoints=False, boxmean=True, notched=True, showlegend=False) for i in range(N)]

fig.add_traces(boxes)

x_all = df.index == df.index
x_all = np.append(x_all, [True, False])

x_some = (df.Mean > 0).values
x_some = np.append(x_some, [False, True])

## the last two traces will be the mean line, and the mean line (with nulls excluded)
fig.add_trace(mean_line)
fig.add_trace(mean_line_exclude_missing)

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[
    dict(type="dropdown", direction="down", buttons=list([
        dict(label="Include missing data", method="update", args=[{"visible": x_all}]),
        dict(label="Exclude missing data", method="update", args=[{"visible": x_some}])
    ]), pad={"l": 10, "t": 10}, showactive=True, x=0.23, xanchor="left", y=1.1, yanchor="top")])

z = fig.to_dict()
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Derek! I can confirm that this workaround works for me as well. I still cannot wrap my head around on why these labels persist even if the scatter plot is adjusting correctly in my original code.

Comment: @Thanos in your original code, you're plotting `x=df.X` and `y=df.Mean` in your scatter, and that df includes null values